# Object Base Domain Not Allowed: error when tried to implement Facebook like button

Tags: facebook

```
Object Base Domain Not Allowed: Object at URL 'http://www.kripalphotography.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because the domain 'www.kripalphotography.com' is not allowed for the specified application id '404118679628536'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/404118679628536.
```

I am getting this error all the time when i debug.I am trying to implement like button on my wordpress site www.kripalphotography.com as problem persist with facebook 'like' button. I am using **Facebook Open Graph protocol plugin v2.0.2** to generate meta dynamically on header.php .Meta tags generated are:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1118311203">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="404118679628536">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kripalphotography.com/home">
<meta property="og:title" content="Kripal Photography">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="kripalphotography.com">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kripalphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/logo1.png">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
```

can anybody suggest me what is my error here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your domain to the allow domain list of the application on Facebook

Comment: thankx Rawkode your tip did a trick but i get this error:
Parser Mismatched Metadata: 
The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:url => http://www.kripalphotography.com, og:locale:locale => en_US'

Comment: Can you trying putting og:type before all other properties?

Comment: sorry to ask this, where can i get this property to add?  One is i can see in opengraph dashboard from 'get code' menu.

Comment: After a quick search on Google it's a problem with the WordPress plug-in that you're using. The author appears to know about it and is planning the fix. Should you wish to fix this yourself I believe you need to add a trailing slash to the URL and change your locale to lower case.